# Do any US airlines make use of their right to fly between EU airports?

Tags: usa, airlines, eu

According to the [EU–US Open Skies Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU%E2%80%93US_Open_Skies_Agreement),

> Airlines of the United States are also allowed to fly between points
>   in the European Union

Are there any airlines who actually make use of that right? The Wikipedia article only mentions European airlines being upset about the agreement:

> The treaty disappointed European airlines as it was tilted in favor of
>   United States airlines: while they are allowed to operate intra-EU
>   flights, European airlines are not permitted to operate intra-US
>   flights

Comment: Huh, that's too bad.  I would love if a few of those insanely cheap airlines began operating in the US.

Comment: Related news article from USA Today [Should foreign airlines be allowed to fly domestic routes?](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/flights/2014/01/05/elliott-let-foreign-airlines-fly-domestic-routes/4329825/) dated January 6, 2014.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not appear that any US *passenger* airlines currently operate flights within the EU.

I assumed that if any such flight existed, it would be with one of the big four legacy airlines (AA, UA, US, DL) and at least one end would be at a major hub.  I checked the Wikipedia pages for LHR, CDG, FRA and AMS, and none of them show flights on those carriers to other EU airports.

However, based on those same Wikipedia pages, it does appear that the US *cargo* airlines FedEx Express and UPS Airlines operate many flights within the EU.

Comment: There is an Cathray Pacfic flight that goes from ATL->ANC->HKG

Comment: @monksy: Cathay Pacific is not an EU airline, of course.  Also, my understanding is that in these cases, the foreign airline is only allowed to carry passengers continuing to/from the foreign airport; in your example ATL-ANC-HKG, you wouldn't be allowed to buy a ticket for just the ATL-ANC segment.

Comment: FedEx and UPS have had major operations in Europe for quite some time. I'd be surprised if they only started operating intra-European flights in 2007 -- could there have been some other deal in place for cargo airlines prior to then?

Comment: @DavidRicherby both have European subsidiaries, the flights operate under technical control of those, bypassing any EU/US treaties.

Comment: @jwenting Thanks. Do you know if their intra-European flights are still operated by the EU-based subsidiaries? If so, mention of FedEx and UPS in this answer is something of a red herring.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Both are large companies, large companies are not quick or eager to change something that works. And why would UPS Germany ask for UPS America to schedule a flight for them between Frankfurt and Madrid if they can do it themselves?

Comment: @monksy I think that Cathay flight is actually a cargo flight, not a passenger flight. Airlines used to stop in Anchorage on trans-pac flights to refuel, but most don't nowadays. Cargo flights still do, though. I don't think Cathay has any passenger flights to Atlanta. Also, as Nate said, even when airlines did stop in Anchorage, they were not allowed to sell tickets for just the domestic portion of the trip. All of the passengers had to be originating in or going to a foreign city. For instance, you can't book a ticket to Guam from the mainland on a non-U.S. airline.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, the Pan-am flight which crashed in Lockerbie in 1987 began in Frankfurt, before stopping in London and on to the USA. Of course this was a feeder I guess, rather than an intra EU flight, but I'd be surprised if they hadn't occurred in the meantime.

Comment: Pan Am did operate German domestic and intra-European flights out of Berlin and Frankfurt till the bitter end.